# My Android App is Taking Forever to deploy?

Tags: android

I have built several android apps before. I am not a novice, but I am truly stumped why this particular app I am working on takes several minutes to compile and deploy.  Where does one even begin to resolve such a problem! Its slowing my whole development effort as the whole change/feedback cycle is talking too long. I have several libraries like flurry(used this before w/o this issue), and I am using the actionbar sherlock. That's about it.

Comment: I think you should go through and accept answers for your other questions first.. More likely to get a response

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your eclipse/JVM is about to run into out of memory

When this was happening to me, I edited eclipse.ini and changed this

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Also modify any other parameter related to memory

Also make sure that your apk size is not too large.